# How do NAs behave in R

Tags: r, math

The behaviour of NA in R is often times confusing. For example, `NA + 1` returns `NA` but `NA^0` returns `1`. This post has two fold objectives:

1. To answer: why does NA behave like this?
2. And more personal, to put out in wider audience, what I have come to understand over time and validate that understanding

Comment: If the result depends on the unknown value, then the result is `NA`. If the result not depends on the unknown value, then the result is a defined value, e.g. for every value of x the result of x^0 is 1 - so also `NA^0` is 1.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation define NA as:

> NA is a logical constant of length 1 which contains the missing value indicator. NA can be coerced to any other vector type except raw. There are also constants NA_integer_, NA_real_, NA_complex_ and NA_character_ of the other atomic vector types which support missing values

In simple words, it just tells you that a value is missing. The type of `NA` is logical, whic you can acertain by:

```r
typeof(NA)
#> [1] "logical"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Note this does not mean, the missing value is of type logical. It could be of anytype, after all it's missing.

The computations with `NA` usually returns `NA` (except some cases).

#### Maths with NA

Numeric calculations with `NA` usually returns `NA`.

```r
NA + 1
#> [1] NA
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

But not `NA^0`

```r
NA^0
#> [1] 1
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

To understand it better, one thing to remember in R is that everything that happens in R is a functional call. So you could rewrite the above as following.

```r
`^`(NA,0)
#> [1] 1
```

Base functions (generally), attempts to coerce one atomic vector to another, if in case the two are of different type. One example of this is following, in which, LHS 1, which is of numeric type gets coerced to character type.

```r
1 == "1"
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

When this happens, the `NA` gets coerced to `NA_ineger_` and then it becomes an identity i.e. any number raised to power zero is 1. As expected, when tried `NA_character_`, it throws an error.

```r
NA_integer_^0
#> [1] 1
NA_real_^0
#> [1] 1
NA_complex_^0
#> [1] 1+0i
NA_character_^0
#> Error in NA_character_^0: non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

#### Logics with `NA`

Often times we want to check if a particular variable (say `x`) is `NA` or not and intuitively we run the following expecting it to return either TRUE or FALSE.

```r
x == NA
#> NA
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

This might seem unexpected, but it makes sense, as `x` could be anything (like a vector, NA, integer etc) therefore the result is ambiguous. Next, the obvious question is what happens if we compare `NA==NA`. That too results in `NA`, still the result is ambiguous as it doesn't make sense to compare two missing values. Same goes with other operators as well like `>, <, !=, &, |, ||, &&`. To check if a value is `NA`, use `is.na()`.

```r
NA == NA
#> [1] NA
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

But in case of certain identities, which are TRUE (or FALSE) irrespective of the values, the result is TRUE (or FALSE). For example:

1. The result of expression `a AND b` is TRUE if and only if both `a` and `b` are TRUE. In all other cases it's FALSE.<sup>[1](https://pages.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs201/NOTES/chap03/logical.html)</sup>

```r
FALSE && NA
#> [1] FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

2. The result of expression `a OR b` is FALSE if and only if both `a` and `b` are FALSE. In all other cases it's TRUE.<sup>[2](https://pages.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs201/NOTES/chap03/logical.html)</sup>

```r
TRUE || NA
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Let's view this philosophically. `NA` is the missing value indicator. It means that there is no value. If you do not know a number x, then x + 1 is un-kown as well.

However, for any x number, x^0 = 1, therefore we can ignore the input of x to actually compute the output.

Comment: Isn't that argument contradicting itself? If it's a missing value, how do we know it's a number? If we assume the missing value to be a number then it makes sense that NA^0=1, but if we assume it to be a character then it should throw an error.

Comment: @monte not really. NA means that we don't have a value, it is the "un-known". This is a superposition to any un-kown thing and not a concrete value that we do not possess. I do not know your real name, but I know that you *have* a name which is a single value. The NA in the language does not represent a specific un-known value, it is the abstract concept of the un-known. So, it is up to convention and definition how do we handle the un-known. We can make it to be an absorbing element to any operator, or we can throw an error whenever it is used as an operand (except checking for NA)

Comment: @monte or we can use what we know. When you say NA^0, then the code already assumed that NA^0 is a sensible operation, which means that it already assumed that NA is a number. Do you know what the number was? No, but you know what x^0 is. If we approach the question as you have suggested, not accepting the assumption of the code, then what the result of "abc"^0 is? It should be an error, right? So, if we do not know whether NA^0 is doable (we don't play along with the assumption of the code), then it is reasonable to throw an error. Is that a good idea?

Comment: @monte throwing an error just because we do not accept that NA^0 is a number on the 0th power is a bad idea (of course, it could be a vector, but a vector is a multidimensional point in abstract terms). It's playing against the best indicator of what NA is, which, in our case is the ^ operator. So, should we say that we don't know what x ^ 0 is? If you ask virtually any person having at least basic knowledge in mathematics, he/she will tell you that x ^ 0 is 1. Of course you didn't tell them that x is a number, but they have accepted its numeric nature to give you a sensible answer.